# Making code (more) cross platform

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, filesystems

I am trying to make my (currently working on windows) code a bit more platform independent. This small snippet is for opening a text file (for reading/writing).

As with modern pcs many files are stored as unicode. Now In this question I am especially wondering what the right way to **open** such a file is. (Where the filename may be unicode).

On windows, using microsoft visual studio, I used

```
char* filename("c:\\\xD0\x92.txt");

#ifdef _WIN32
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
#else
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> converter; 
//non windows wstring = utf8
#endif

std::wstring wfilename(converter.from_bytes(filename));


std::fstream fstream(wfilename);
```

However I just now realized this isn't standard C++11, instead a visual studio (only?) extension. However when I try on windows to first convert the widestring to an UTF-8 std::string and open the file that way the fstream doesn't recognize the filename.
So what is the cross platform solution? - Should I just expect std::fstream to always accept a widestring input? Or should I expect this on windows always?

And if possix systems don't use widestrings for their directories; what do they use?

Comment: Decent read: http://www.utf8everywhere.org/#how

Comment: "This code is not multi-platform and may have to be changed manually in the future." - So that site is basically saying I have to suck it up and macro myself around?

Comment: File names are platform dependent. Windows generally wants UTF-16; Linux UTF-8. On Windows, `fstream` constructor taking `char*` expects the string to be in system default ANSI codepage (aka `CP_ACP`); a non-standard constructor taking `wchar_t*` expects UTF-16. On Linux, only `char*` constructor is available; I believe it expects UTF-8.

Comment: On Windows wchar_t is UTF-16. On Linux wchar_t is UTF-32 (depending on compiler setings). On Windows char is an ANSI code page. On Linux char is UTF-8 (I think? also depending on compiler settings). As much as the holy standard tries to give us cross-platform capability, in my opinion it's rather lagging behind reality in regard to character encodings. Admittedly my experience in cross-platform development is limited, but it seems like you need to put in a significant amount of effort (typedefs, wrapper classes, etc) before you can get something actually effective.

Comment: This question belongs on CodeReview@StackExchange.com because it is requesting a review of code.

Comment: Check out [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), which deals with many platform-specific issues for you.

Comment: @usta That's kind of moving the problem - as the problem is now in `filesystem::path` vs `filesystem::wpath`. Non wide paths can't handle unicode-filenames on windows. So you still have to provide different codepaths/typedefs for different oses

Comment: I wonder why you just can't "go with the flow" and simply use wchar_t and `L"filename"` and the standard wide library calls and accept that your wide chars won't be the same width on different computers.

Comment: @MrLister Since widecharacters won't work for posix based filesystems.

Comment: Note that your file-naming convention is not cross platform: `"c:\\\xD0\x92.txt"` would become something like `/home/xD0/x92.txt` on Unix/Linux systems.

Comment: @paul23 Not anymore. There is no `wpath` in the latest version of [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html) - Version 3, which is the basis for the in-progress standardization. So you can just use `path` everywhere without needing platform-conditional typedefs.